# External Native Build Issues Build command failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

**I have existing NDK project which is already developed. I import it in Android Studio 2.3.3 version. I got following type of error after importing project.**

```
External Native Build Issues
Build command failed.
Error while executing 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\...\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\...\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/ProjectNameFolder/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\ProjectNameFolder\new\Project\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: D:\...\jni\Android.mk    
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\...\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\ProjectNameFolder\new\Project\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/ProjectNameFolder/new/Project/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\ProjectNameFolder\new\Project\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: D:\...\src\main\jni\Android.mk    
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk
Error:(48, 0) D:\DemoProject: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) Source: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) Code: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) And: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) Apk\new\Project\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(100, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) D:\ProjectNameFolder: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) Source: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) Code: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) And: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(48, 0) Apk\new\Project\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(100, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk">Open File</a>
```

Comment: Post your gradle script and Application.mk.

Comment: I am facing same issue did you found any solution